# Separating two different sem into different tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I wanted to know how to call two data from my model. To explain more further I wanted this to happen, this is my model:

```
function result_getGrades($studentid)
        {

            $sql=   "   
                    SELECT g.studentid, sb.subjectcode, s.description, g.final,sb.sem,sb.sy
                    FROM grades g 

                    JOIN subjectblocking sb ON g.blockcode=sb.blockcode

                    JOIN subjects s ON sb.subjectcode=s.subjectcode

                    WHERE g.studentid='$studentid'
                    ORDER BY sb.sem ASC, sb.sy ASC;


                    ";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $result->result();
            return $result;
        }
```

and this is the view:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="well">
            <table class="table">

                <thead>
                    <th>Subject Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Sem</th>
                    <th>School Year</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                </thead>
        <?php foreach ($query as $row){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->subjectcode;?><br></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->description;?><br></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->sem;?><br></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->sy;?><br></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->final;?><br></td>
                    </tr>

        <?php } ?>  
            </table>
```

This is how it looked like, as you can see it is in one table, I wanted to separate the table that has different sem, how can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to deviate from a traditional foreach loop and do some while loops as follows (following code is untested):

```
<?php 
while($row = current($query)) {
    // Echo the table HTML
    ?>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Subject Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Sem</th>
        <th>School Year</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    // Loop for all the same "sem"s
    do {
        // Echo the HTML
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->subjectcode;?><br></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->description;?><br></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->sem;?><br></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->sy;?><br></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->final;?><br></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        // Set the pointer the the next value in the array and fetch the row
        $nextRow = next($query);
        // If the next row exists, get the "sem" that's next
        if($nextRow) {
            $nextSem = $nextRow->sem;
        }
        else {
            $nextSem = null;
        }
    }
    // Loop while the upcoming "sem" is the same as the one we just printed
    while($nextSem === $row->sem);
    // Echo the end of the table body
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <?php
}
```

The other option is sticking with the foreach loop. but conditionally prepending / appending the `<table>` tags if the "sem" is different.

Comment: It separated however there is no grade and only the first column is on loop

Comment: I just jotted the code without testing it. This is sort of an example of an alternate method to get what you want. Hopefully you can figure out any bugs that are in there :).